# Navigation Bar Inner Tab Positioning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar

I'm making a Drop Down Navigation bar using CSS and HTML. The below image is the sort of thing I am trying to achieve.

[image: Drop Down Navigation Bar]

In the code, `OuterTab1` and `OuterTab2` are always lower than `Tab2` although I want them at the same height like in the example image.

I know this doesn't sound very clear, please check here: http://jsfiddle.net/442xM/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Tab1</li>
        <li>Tab2
            <ul>
                <li>OuterTab1</li>
                <li>OuterTab2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the absolutely positioned submenu (`<ul>`) relative to the hovered `<li>`. so apply `position:relative;` for the `<li>`

```
li {
    position:relative; /* add this*/
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/442xM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below. Its all about positioning the element.

```
 .button {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
* {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
}
nav {
background-color: black;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
width: 452px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
ul, ol {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
}
li {
vertical-align: top;
width: 100px;
height: 15px;
text-align: left;
background-color: black;
padding: 5px;
position:relative;
}
 li:hover {
background-color: grey;
}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
text-align: left;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
left: 100%;
top:0;
z-index: 5;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.Arrow {
float: right;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/442xM/3/)